# rubymotion Cannot find executable for CFBundle

Tags: rubymotion

I just installed RubyMotion on my iMac.

I created my first app -  Hello

This is the code:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
  @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
  @window.rootViewController = HelloViewController.alloc.init
  @window.rootViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = true
  @window.makeKeyAndVisible
  true
  end
end
```

I run `$ Rake` and the IOS Simulator start up.  And I get this error:

```
2014-04-25 18:58:03.157 Hello[10488:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8d8a130 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

I tried this from another question:

```
Temporary workaround: click iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... and run again.
```

But, that didn't fix it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a relatively harmless (I believe) bug in the iOS 7 SDK.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/940094#940094

> I had the same issue and found your post when searching for a solution.  My application appeared to be running fine but I was still getting this message  I was able to eliminate the message on my machine, here is what I had to do;
>
> Stop all execution on the simulator.
>   Go to the simulator's home screen using shift-command-h.
>   Delete the app from the simulator device by holding a click on my program until the delete icon appeared, then click the X to delete.
>   In the iOS Simulator select Reset Content and Settings.
>   Clean the project in Xcode, shift-command-k.
>   Build it and run it.
>
> Note, I was doing steps 4 & 5 but that wasn't working.  It wasn't until I added step 3 (as crazy as it sounds) that it cleared my message.
>
> Hope this works for you!
>
> --Dave

Perhaps deleting the app, resetting, and restarting the iOS simulator would work.

Comment: I reset the iPhone simulator and then restarted and it worked like champ.