# JSON file is not loading in a RubyMotion project

Tags: ruby, json, rubymotion

I'm following a RubyMotion tutorial app ([here](http://pragmaticstudio.com/screencasts/rubymotion)) that has several folders in it. I have one folder containing the Ruby scripts for the app and I have another such folder with images and a JSON file in it. However, I'm having a strange problem where my app's JSON file won't load, while the one in the tutorial will. The part that I'm at in the tutorial (around the timestamp 40:48 in the video) under the file `magic_8ball.rb` looks like this:

```
class Magic8Ball
    def initialize
        @answers = loadAnswers
    end

    def loadAnswers
        answerFile = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("answers", ofType:"json")
        errorPointer = Pointer.new(:object)

        data = NSData.alloc.initWithContentsOfFile(answerFile, options:NSDataReadingUncached, error:errorPointer)

        unless data
            printError errorPointer[0]
            return defaultAnswers
        end

        json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSDataReadingUncached, error:errorPointer)

        unless json
            printError errorPointer[0]
            return defaultAnswers
        end

        json["answers"]
    end

    def defaultAnswers
        ["Yes", "No", "Maybe", "Try again"]
    end

    def printError (error)
        $stderr.puts "Error: #{error.description}"
    end

    def randomAnswer
        @answers.sample
    end
end
```

and the JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "answers":[
        "It is certain",
        "Without a doubt",
        "Definitely",
        "Most likely",
        "Outlook good",
        "Yes!",
        "Try again",
        "Reply hazy",
        "Can't predict",
        "No!",
        "Unlikely",
        "Sources say no",
        "Very doubtful"
    ]
}
```

Also, whenever I run the app with the `rake` command, the terminal throws out this error:

`[55766:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8d88630 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)`

I've looked over my code several times and compared it to the code in the tutorial, but I've had no success in figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to check what's been done in that tutorial but if you've got a file named "file.json" in the /resources folder you can pick up it's content by doing this:

```
file_path = NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource('file', ofType: 'json')
contents = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(file_path)
```

Also, if you want to parse the JSON's content into a dictionary you can use the amazing BubbleWrap gem just add to gemfile:

```
gem "bubble-wrap", "~> 1.5.0", :require => 'bubble-wrap/core'
```

Run bundle command (if you're using bundler) to install the gem, and then you can replace

```
contents = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(file_path)
```

with

```
contents = BW::JSON.parse(NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(file_path))
```

And that's it!

Regarding your code, I do not see anything wrong at first sight. Are you sure you're saving the JSON file inside the /resources folder ? You should be getting an error printed in the console regarding that matter... (not talking about the "Cannot find executable for CFBundle" for which a fast search resulted in: [rubymotion Cannot find executable for CFBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306575/rubymotion-cannot-find-executable-for-cfbundle)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why, but that didn't work. The terminal came up with the same error and the JSON file still hasn't loaded. Here is my modified source: https://gist.github.com/934a4cbf568f81d73022

Comment: It should be contentsOfAnswerFile = BW::JSON.parse(NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(answerFile))

Comment: Also, you're not doing anything with it. Try adding "puts contentsOfAnswerFile" below line 8 to at least see the output in the console

Comment: Darn, it's having the same error, although it is printing out `contentsOfAnswerFile`.

Comment: Well... I have no idea what you're doing. I took the contents of your original Magic8Ball class... created a new RubyMotion project. I've put the class inside the app directory and the JSON inside the resources directory and I called that file 'answers.json'. I run the project and then I did this in the console: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qluytk0r6s3tnf2/Screenshot%202014-08-14%2015.52.46.png). It's working OK.